# Return part of string of every cell in pd.Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

There is a pd.DataFrame
df:

```
  |         crit         |  acc_num |
--|----------------------|----------|
0 | 050_11_20 0021351-05 | 27045980 |   
1 | 051_09_20 0021351-05 | 27145990 |   
2 | 058_77_21 0021351-05 | 27245910 |   
3 | 075_85_21 0021351-05 | 27445920 |
```

All data is str.
**How can I return lines 2,3 which has '21' on position [8,9] in column 'crit'?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str[7:9]` which checks if the characters within that space are equal to '21', and use `loc` to return a filtered `df`:

```
>>> df.loc[df['crit'].str[7:9]=='21']

                   crit   acc_num
2  058_77_21 0021351-05  27245910
3  075_85_21 0021351-05  27445920
```

Using your solution proposed below, I would say it will need a bit of tweaking to work as you want it:

```
>>> df.loc[df.crit.str.split('_').str[2].str[:2]=='21']

Out[37]: 
                   crit   acc_num
2  058_77_21 0021351-05  27245910
3  075_85_21 0021351-05  27445920
```

Hopefully the below can clarify:

```
>>> df.crit.str.split('_')

Out[40]: 
      # Index
       0   1   ------2------ 
0    [050, 11, 20 0021351-05]
1    [051, 09, 20 0021351-05]
2    [058, 77, 21 0021351-05]
3    [075, 85, 21 0021351-05]

>>> df.crit.str.split('_').str[2] # we grab the 2nd

Out[43]: 
0    20 0021351-05
1    20 0021351-05
2    21 0021351-05
3    21 0021351-05

>>> df.crit.str.split('_').str[2].str[:2]=='21' # grab the last 2 parts and check if they are equal to '21'

Out[47]: 
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True

>>> df.loc[df.crit.str.split('_').str[2].str[:2]=='21'] # Boolean indexing

Out[48]: 
                   crit   acc_num
2  058_77_21 0021351-05  27245910
3  075_85_21 0021351-05  27445920
```

Comment: Great! That is a'm looking for. My solution ```df.creation_date.str.split('_').str[2] ``` is a little un-pitonic IMHO...

Comment: Glad it works. Your code will need a bit of tweaking to work in your favour. I have added some steps that will hopefully clarify what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `map()` on column `crit` and then `split()` on string.

```py
d = df.loc[df['crit'].map(lambda x: '21' in x.split(' ')[0].split('_')[-1])]

print(d)
'''
                   crit   acc_num
2  058_77_21 0021351-05  27245910
3  075_85_21 0021351-05  27445920
'''
```

Comment: Interesting. Could you say is your solution more "expensive" than the one above? Your solution looks like more... voluminous?...

Comment: @Vadim.M. Using `timeit.timeit` to test on your given data, it seems my solution is faster than `df.loc[df['crit'].str[7:9]=='21']`.